# Laravel returns the error "Argument 1 passed to ...validateCredentials() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable"

Tags: laravel

User.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $fillable = ['name','email','password'];

}
```

Error occurs when attempting to login in Laravel.

Error:

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of App\User given, called in F:\eStore\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard.php on line 385

Comment: Hi. Please show us your User.php code.

Comment: what is the error you are getting please post the error

Answer (score 0):

You need to add implements `\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` to your `User` model class definition.

```
  class User extends Model implements \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable {
    }
```